# Can you cross-site ping another site using C# or JS/Ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-applications, cross-site, pinging

On our web application I am trying to ping a 3rd party site to see if it is up before redirecting our customers to it.  So far I have not seen a way to do this other than from a desktop app or system console.  Is this possible?  I have heard that there was an image trick in original ASP.

Currently we are using .NET MVC with Javascript.

Thank you,

Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a two stage process where you make an AJAX call and if it works then redirect to the site. For example, the AJAX call could do something like:

```
public bool IsAddressResponsive(string Address)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Address);
    req.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And if the response was true then redirect to the address.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer on this question to do it using jquery.  [how-to-test-a-url-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051272/how-to-test-a-url-in-jquery)

Comment: looks like the external link in the accepted answer changed, it's now http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/jq-plugins/88-jquery-plugin-ajax-head-request.html

Comment: Maybe I am just using it wrong but the plugin seems to be for local url checking.  Meaning www.YourDomain.com/home.html, because if I try www.google.com. I get www.YourDomain.com/www.google.com.

I am looking to check and see if a site like www.YourDomain.com is up from www.MyDomain.com.  If I could do this on the client side that would be awesome because I believe I will have issues when the 3rd party sides are hosted in my customer's intranets.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.  You can use this class to make a request to the 3rd party system.  If it is a ASP.Net web app, you are probably making this call from your code behind.

You will then want to check for a 200 response code.  Things get a little trickier if you have to worry about security, or passing along the users cookies.

Comment: Looks like theBadDawg beat me to it and included a code example as well.  Nice job theBadDawg.