# JQuery GET, how to make sort of fire and forget

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a search result page and on page ready I have ajax GET to pre-request each result item url in order to pre cache those pages.

eg.

```
$('.link').each(function(){
  $.get($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Putting the argument of whether this is the right approach aside, how do I make an ajax GET request in jQuery that requests the page, wait for the status code change then abort the request (in other words, don't need to receive the content)?

I have come across [this article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajaxian-fire-and-forget-pattern), but I have no idea how to incorporate this into jQuery GET function.

Comment: How does the browser pre-cache if you cancel the request before the content is received?

Comment: cache manifest? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5

Comment: No, I would like the server to pre cache the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply abort the AJAX call once you sent it.  You might be able to use the `abort()` function.  There are other [properties of the AJAX object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that you might find useful.

```
var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "server.php",
    data: "name=James&location=Auckland",
    success: function(response){
       alert( "Response: " + response );
    }
});

//abort the request
ajaxCall.abort();
```

If all you want to do is fire off an AJAX request and handle statusCode changes, this code might be useful.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      alert("request successful");
    }
  }
});
```

This callback fires when the `200` status code is set - a complete request.  You can change this code to whatever status code you are looking to detect. With in that callback, you can then call the `abort()` function.

Comment: does the content of the request get loaded when status code change handler function fires?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  You could see that if you simply printed the AJAX object to the console.

Comment: Well the example I gave was a `200 OK` response.  You can change that to whatever status code you want...

Answer (score 0):

What I do is this:

```
var $page = $('<div>').load('/somepage body', function() {
    // code to do something when its loaded
});
```

If you don't put a selector, it will fire scripts within. You can do that too but you have to code your scripts accordingly.

But to answer your specific question:

```
var pages = [];

function allLoaded() {
   console.log('all pages loaded');
}

$('.link').each(function(){
    var $page = $('<div>'), href = $(this).attr('href');
    $page.load(href + ' body', function() {
       pages.push({href: href, html : $page.html()});
       if (pages.length === $('.link').length) {
          allLoaded();
       }
    }
});
```

Don't you just love closures?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **synchronous** AJAX call is what you are looking for.  Your script will wait until the request has been completed and only then continue to run. You could then check the [`status` property of the AJAX object.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    url: "server.php",
    data: "name=James&location=Auckland",
});
if (ajaxCall.status == 200){
  // request executed successfully 
}
```

> #### async
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal of this question was to make a request, get the status of the url, but then NOT download the content, then your best bet is not to override the AJAX GET HTTP method but rather use the HEAD HTTP method.

Stack overflow:

[How to test a URL in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051272/how-to-test-a-url-in-jquery)

JQuery Docs (Look at the "type" property):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings